# Is this a proper algebraic proof that $Re(z)\leq\left|z\right|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Given that $z=(x+iy)\in \mathbb{C}$, I'm supposed to show that $Re(z)\leq\left|z\right|$.

This is my attempt:

Note that $\sqrt{Re(z)} = \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Since $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, this shows that $x = Re(z) \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \left|z\right|$.

Is this proof sound mathematically? How could I make it better? Is there another, more ingenious way you would go about it?

**Updated proof (thanks to @Nameless)**:

Since $Re(z) = x \leq x^2 \leq x^2 + y^2$, then we see that $\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Since $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, it follows that $x = Re(z) \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \left|z\right|$, which is what was to be shown.

Is this version better? Maybe I'm wording it incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean $x^2 \leq x^2 + y^2$? Note that $y^2$ is a nonnegative real number.

Comment: What do you mean? $\left|z\right|$ is defined as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and that's what I have to show (in)equality of. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Well, do you agree what I wrote is correct first? If so, what happens if you take the square root (positive square root) on both sides?

Comment: Ah - yeah I see now. Thanks - that's a clean way to go about it.

Comment: BTW - the original proof I made is still technically valid, right?

Comment: You wrote $\sqrt x \leq \sqrt{x^2}$, so what if $x = 1/2$?

Comment: What you've shown (or would have shown if Nameless wasn't correct about one step) is actually $\sqrt{Re(z)} \le |z|$. You don't need the square root of $Re(z)$.

Comment: I've updated the proof attempt in the OP. Does it look better?

Comment: And $\sqrt {x^2} = x$ only when $x \ge 0$, which you are not guaranteed is true for $Re(z)$. These are small issues that are easily corrected, but they do need corrected.

Comment: So from what I read, your updated proof is essentially the same as your first proof...

Comment: $x\le x^2$ does not always hold.   Consider $x=\frac 1 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is easier to write the flow as

$$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge \sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\left|\text{Re}(z)\right|\ge \text{Re}(z)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\Re z > |z|$, then $|z|^2 = (\Re z)^2 + (\Im z)^2 \ge (\Re z)^2 > |z|^2$, a contradiction; hence $\Re z \le |z|$.